# ReduxForm is rendered twice when mounted via enzyme

Tags: react-redux, enzyme, redux-form

I'm trying to align my tests to follow breaking changes after upgrading react-redux to 6.0.0 and redux-form to 8.1.0 (connected components do not take store in props any longer)

I needed to wrap my connected component in  from react-redux in tests and use mount to get to actual component but now ReduxForm is rendered twice.
I tried to use hostNodes() method but it returns 0 elements.
Any ideas how to fix it?

Here is the test:

```
import React from 'react'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import PasswordResetContainer from './PasswordResetContainer'

describe('PasswordResetContainer', () => {
  it('should render only one ReduxForm', () => {
    const mockStore = configureStore()
    const initialState = {}
    const store = mockStore(initialState)
    const wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store}><PasswordResetContainer /></Provider>)

    const form = wrapper.find('ReduxForm')
    console.log(form.debug())
    expect(form.length).toEqual(1)
  })
```

And PasswordResetContainer looks like this:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import PasswordReset from './PasswordReset'
import { resetPassword } from '../Actions'

export const validate = (values) => {
  const errors = {}

  if (!values.email) {
    errors.email = 'E-mail cannot be empty.'
  } else if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(values.email)) {
    errors.email = 'Invalid e-mail.'
  }
  return errors
}

export default connect(null, { resetPassword })(
  reduxForm(
    { form: 'passwordReset',
      validate
    })(PasswordReset))
```

Output from test is following:

```
PasswordResetContainer › should render only one ReduxForm

    expect(received).toEqual(expected)

    Expected value to equal:
      1
    Received:
      2
```

**Edit (partial solution found):**

When I changed `wrapper.find('ReduxForm')`
into `wrapper.find('ReduxForm>Hoc>ReduxForm')` it started to work.
Why do I need to do such a magic?

Comment: Console log run in test prints this https://pastebin.com/vHn5Gy6t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix is on library mods to create but if the forms are identical, one quick way to get around the issue is to call first() after find so that

```
wrapper.find('ReduxForm')
```

looks like:

```
wrapper.find('ReduxForm').first()
```

Comment: Yeah, but that can hide problems. What if someone else add a code to create two ReduxForms (4 would be generated) ?